# Can't differentiate the two expressions supposed to work in the same way

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, conditional-statements

Few days back I created ***[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56494865/unable-to-let-my-script-keep-trying-for-few-times-when-a-condition-is-not-met)***, to seek any solution as to how I can let my script loop in such a way so that the script will use few links to check whether my defined `title` (supposed to be extracted from each link) is nothing for `four` times. If the `title` is still nothing then the script will `break` the `loop` and go for another link to repeat the same.

This is how I got success--► By changing `fetch_data(link)` to `return fetch_data(link)` and defining `counter=0` outside `while loop` but inside `if` statement.

Rectified script:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = [
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort=newest&page=2",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort=newest&page=3",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort=newest&page=4"
]
counter = 0

def fetch_data(link):
    global counter
    res = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    try:
        title = soup.select_one("p.tcode").text
    except AttributeError: title = ""

    if not title:
        while counter<=3:
            time.sleep(1)
            print("trying {} times".format(counter))
            counter += 1
            return fetch_data(link) #First fix
        counter=0 #Second fix

    print("tried with this link:",link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for link in links:
        fetch_data(link)
```

This is the output the above script produces (as desired):

```
trying 0 times
trying 1 times
trying 2 times
trying 3 times
tried with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort=newest&page=2
trying 0 times
trying 1 times
trying 2 times
trying 3 times
tried with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort=newest&page=3
trying 0 times
trying 1 times
trying 2 times
trying 3 times
tried with this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping?sort=newest&page=4
```

`I used wrong selector within my script so that I can let it meet the condition I've defined above.`

> ***Why should I use `return fetch_data(link)` instead of `fetch_data(link)` as the expressions work identically most of the times?***

Comment: Side-note: Here your explicit return only every applies to failed cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop inside your function will initiate a recursive call if it fails to fetch the title. It works when you use `return fetch_data(link)` since whenever the counter is less than or equal to 3 `while counter<=3`, it will exit the function immediately at the end of the while loop, thus not going down to the lower line that will reset the counter to 0 `counter=0`. Since the counter is a global variable and only increases by 1 for each recursion depth, you will only have a maximum 4 recursion depths as anytime the `counter` is larger than 3, it won't go into the while loop that will call another `fetch_data(link)`.

```
fetch_data (counter=0)
  --> fetch_data (counter=1)
    --> fetch_data (counter=2)
      --> fetch_data (counter=3)
        --> fetch_data (counter=4) 
        - not go into while loop, reset counter, print url
        - return to above function
      - return to above function
    - return to above function
  - return to above function
```

If you use `fetch_data(link)`, the function will still initiate a recursive call in the while loop. However, not exit immediately and will reset the counter to 0. This is dangerous because after your counter goes to 4, the function and go back to the while loop of the previous function call inside the while loop, the while loop will not break and continue to initiate additional recursive calls because the counter is currently set to 0 which is <= 3. This will eventually reach the maximum recursion depth and will crash the program.

```
fetch_data (counter=0)
  --> fetch_data (counter=1)
    --> fetch_data (counter=2)
      --> fetch_data (counter=3)
        --> fetch_data (counter=4) 
        - not go into while loop, !!!reset counter!!!, print url
        - return to above function
      - not return to above function call
      - since counter = 0, continue the while loop
        --> fetch_data (counter=1)
          --> fetch_data (counter=2)
            --> fetch_data (counter=3)
...
```

Comment: Now it makes sense @VietHTran. Thanks for the clarity of things.